# user prompted for file export location

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable

I made a pretty simple stroke calculator for golf a friend wanted, the data entered is compiled into a Jtable in netbeans, and I am trying to add an export button that exports the data to excel.

I have managed to get the data exported but what I can't seem to do is figure out how to prompt the user for where the file should be exported to, currently it goes to the destination I predestined in the code. So in other words how do I go about getting the generic window that comes up when saving a file in most programs.

Answer (score 2):

> in other words how do I go about getting the generic window that comes up when saving a file in most programs

See [How to Use a File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#eg). Basically something like

```
JFileChoooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int result = chooser.showSaveDialog(parent);
```

See the tutorial for complete examples. Here's a real simple one

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class ChooserDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "JFileChooser, you're my only friend.";

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int result = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
                writer.write(text);
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }  
}
```